# JMeter is creating multiple entries when run from CMD line

Tags: java, cmd, jmeter

When I run JMeter from CMD line it is creating multiple entries on aggregate report. I am running LOGIN to LOGOUT script with 30 users having ramp up 2 seconds. After the run is complete and when I browse my .csv file from JMeter it is creating multiple entries instead of 1. For example Login,Login-0,Login-1,Login-2 to Login-27. Same thing with Dashboard which comes after Login but for Dashboard it is creating 54 entries like Dashboard, Dashboard-0,Dashboard-10,Dashboard-53, Dashboard-54 etc etc. When I run same script from JMeter GUI mode it is only creating 1 entry. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you're using a [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/JMeter-Transaction-controller-behavior/)? If yes, untick `Generate parent sample` box and call `Apply Naming Policy` from the context menu, this way JMeter will generate a "good" names for the Transaction Controller's children which can be used for proper dashboard report generation including calculation of concurrency.

[image]

More information: [Transaction Controller Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#transaction_controller_requirements)